# Is having a single `IndexWriter` instance in Lucene a good idea?

Tags: java, search-engine

I am trying to understand how Lucene should be used.

From what I have read, creating an `IndexReader` is costly, so using a `Search Manager` shoulg be the right choice. However, a `SearchManager` should be produced by a `NRTManager`(which, by the way, should replace the `IndexWriter` for every add or delete operation performed). But in order to have a `NRTManager`, I should first have an `IndexWriter`, and here comes my problem.

The documentation says:

- an IndexWriter is thread-safe
- the constructor of this class takes a `Directory` object, so it seems creating an instace should be costly(as in the case of an IndexReader)
- all changes are buffered and flushed periodically(so they seem to encourage using a single instance)

  but:
- the changes, although flushed will only be visible after `commit` or `close`
- after finished making updates(add/delete), the instance should be closed
- I also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374419/forgot-to-close-the-lucene-indexwriter-after-adding-documents-to-the-index where it is said that not closing a writer might ruin everything

So what am I really supposed to do? Is having a single `IndexWriter` instance a good idea (make only `commit` and never `close` it)?

**EDIT:** What is more, if I use `NRTManager`, how can I make a `commit`? Is it even possible?

Comment: I love these absolutely terrible class names.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, how do we start. First of all this is written based on Lucene 3.6.
NRTManager is used for Near-Realtime-Scenarios where Writing and Reading is very close after each other. An Example would be Twitter (that is actually using a modified Version of Lucene). In these cases you are not suppost to close your IndexWriter as all changes that occure are being tracked by NRTManager.TrackingIndexWriter - use NRTManagerReopenThread to periodicly trigger refreshes on the Searcher Threads.

For non-realtime scenarios you rather want to use the SearcherManager to acquire IndexSearcher and an instance of IndexWriter to write Documents. After a set of Documents is written to the index (or on random base) use ReferenceManager.maybeRefresh (extended by SearcherManager) to refresh the Searcher Threads.

To sum up:

- You can have a single instance of IndexWriter and commit your changes. You can as well have multiple threads of IndexWriter writing on one index with ConcurrentMergeScheduler.
- Close your IndexWriter only if you are sure that you do not have any changes to do on the index (mind that it is very coastly to open an IndexWriter)
- You never commit an NRTManager as all changes are being tracked.

Comment: How do I deal with the case when the server shuts down before the changes in memory are committed? Do I listen for `contextDestroyed` in `contextListener` and call `IndexWriter#submit` then close the index writer?